# How do I get data from 0 of the index $.each

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

How do I get value.email from only position 0 of the index?

I only want the value.email from the first item returned in my JSON call.

```
$.each(data.DATA, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.EMAIL);

});
```

I have tried the following but this generates an error.

```
$.each(data.DATA[0], function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.EMAIL);

});
```

Comment: why even loop then?  just use the index

Comment: For future posts why the markdown, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Wasn't me who marked you down.. i'll even you out though

Comment: No that's fine, It just I assumed I have asked this one correctly with examples and direct. anyhow yes 100% right no need to loop here. I could have broken out of the loop, it thats what i needed. thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lose the `$.each`, just do `console.log(data.DATA[0].EMAIL)`.